# Problrm with inserting MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am coding an posting form for a website. It lets a user add text, or text and one or several images. When a user only inputs text, everything works flawlessly. When a user wants to add a picture to the post, the image uploading works, but then the text isn't added to the MySQL database.

```
function uploadImg($filesvar, $folder){
    $num = 1;
    $names = [];
    $allFiles = [];
    $uploadOk = 1;
    foreach($_FILES[$filesvar]['name'] as $x => $name){
        $type = pathinfo($name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if($type !== "jpg" && $type !== "png" && $type !== "jpeg" && $type !== "gif" ) {
            echo "<br>Bare JPG, JPEG, PNG og GIF filer er tillatt.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }else{
            if (($_FILES[$filesvar]['size'][$x] < 100) || ($_FILES[$filesvar]['size'][$x] > 50*1024*1024)){
                echo "<br>En eller flere av filen(e) er for stor(e)";
                $uploadOk = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if($uploadOk == 1){
        foreach($_FILES[$filesvar]['name'] as $x => $name){
            $type = pathinfo($name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $target = $folder . date('dmyHis') . "." . $type;
            if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$target)){
                $target =  $folder . date('dmyHis') . $num . "." . $type;
                $num += 1;
            }
            array_push($names, $target);
            if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$filesvar]["tmp_name"][$x], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$target)){echo "ERROR";}
        }
        return $names;
    }else{
        return "ERROR";
    }
}
```

This ^ is my upload function. It seems to work as it should. It passes an array to the next function if the upload went well:

```
function ny_nyhet($Name, $Message) {
    if($Message!==""){
        if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][0])){
            $files = uploadImg('userfile', '/img/Nyheter/');
            if($files !== "ERROR"){
                foreach($files as $file){
                    $Message = $Message.'<br><a href="'.$file.'"><img src="'.$file.'"></a>';
                }
                insert_mysql("IP", "DATABASE", "USER", "PASSWORD", "TABLE", "ID, Name, Message", "``,`".$Name."`,`".$Message."`");
            }else{
                echo "<br>En feil oppstod";
            }
        }else{
            insert_mysql("IP", "DATABASE", "USER", "PASSWORD", "TABLE", "ID, Name, Message", "'','".$Name."','".$Message."'");
        }
    }
}
```

At this point, the code also works at it should. Except for the part:

```
insert_mysql("IP", "DATABASE", "USER", "PASSWORD", "TABLE", "ID, Name, Message", "``,`".$Name."`,`".$Message."`");
```

When a user only uses text, this works fine, but when the code for images is added, it doesn't work. I tested using the generated code directly in phpmyadmin which gave me a formatting error. I don't see what the error might be.

```
function insert_mysql($Server, $Database, $User, $Pass, $Table, $Names, $Values) {
    $con=mysqli_connect($Server, $User, $Pass, $Database);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `".$Table."` (".$Names.") VALUES(".$Values.")");
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

This code ^ is what I use to add to the database. It might help, but I don't know what, or where the actual problem is. Have I done a silly mistake, or is it that the text needs to be formatted properly? I hope somebody can give me an answer.

MySQL Query:
INSERT INTO `nyheter` (ID, Name, Message) VALUES(``,`Admin`,`<p>asdsadasda</p> <br><a href="/img/Nyheter/290315005049.jpg"><img src="/img/Nyheter/290315005049.jpg"></a><br><a href="/img/Nyheter/2903150050491.jpg"><img src="/img/Nyheter/2903150050491.jpg"></a><br><a href="/img/Nyheter/2903150050492.jpg"><img src="/img/Nyheter/2903150050492.jpg"></a>`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) `mysqli_query` should return a result of the transaction. Check for errors, and echo them out to find out what can be causing the issue.

```
function insert_mysql($Server, $Database, $User, $Pass, $Table, $Names, $Values) {
    $con=mysqli_connect($Server, $User, $Pass, $Database);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    mysqli_query($con,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $res = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `".$Table."` (".$Names.") VALUES(".$Values.")");
    if ( !$res ) { die('Error inserting into db: ' . mysqli_error($con)); }
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

**PLEASE** also have a look at [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) (`mysqli_stmt::bind_param`) on how to properly bind parameters to a query. As an alternative you can use [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) as well.

Comment: It echoed Error inserting into db: Unknown column '' in 'field list'

Comment: Echo out the query, and see where the problem is.

Comment: I added the query to my original post. I can't really see a direct problem.

Comment: You're trying to insert `\`\``. Backticks in this instance represent a field (aka column) in the database, and there is no empty field in your database. Try changing it to null, or '', and it should work properly.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know backticks have a specific role in MySQL. I thought  `` '' "" was the same thing.